# docker - RTMP nginx server access only from phone

Tags: docker, nginx, rtmp, nginx-rtmp

I am quite new to this Docker universe. What I am trying to do is creating a RTMP server which I can stream to from my phone and then use VLC media player to playback the network stream.

I installed this container [tiangolo/nginx-rtmp](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/nginx-rtmp) and ran it. My first problem was finding the right IP, but I found out it being the WSL ethernet IP). From my own PC where I have docker, I am able to stream (via OBS) to the RTMP server and pickup the networkstream with VLC. However, when I try to stream from my phone, the URL or network connection can not connect to the server. It must be a network or portforward problem. I've attached my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file that I have tried to add a some things to *hopefully* make it accessible from my phone as well. I've found the commands from this list of commands for [nginx](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives).

```
worker_processes auto;
rtmp_auto_push on;
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        listen [::]:1935 ipv6only=on;

        application webcam {
            live on;
            record off;
            allow publish 127.0.0.1;
            pull rtmp://172.24.160.1/webcam;
            allow play all;
            allow publish all;
        }
    }
}
```

I've not done anything else but to install docker, install the image and edited the conf without luck.

I've tried to change the configuration file of nginx to have the right network settings, but I am still not able to connect to the RTMP from my phone.